# magit equivalent of gitk's "Diff this -> selected"

Tags: magit, git

gitk has a feature where you select one commit, then right-click another and can choose to either "Diff this -> selected" or "Diff selected -> this".

Is something like this possible in `magit-log`? Meaning, place point on a commit, press something, place point on another commit, and get a diff between the two commits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press <kbd>C-SPC</kbd> (`set-mark-command`), move to the other commit, and press <kbd>d d</kbd>. Many other command that normally act on the thing at point, act on the things in the region instead when that is active. E.g. you could cherry-pick all commits in the region or stage all files in the region. <kbd>d d</kbd> is actually a special case because it only does something with the commits "at the edges of the region" instead of all the commits in the region.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Jonas! I'll just add that shift + arrow keys work too if you have that enabled.

Comment: You can also stage just part of a hunk using the region. However in that case shift + arrow keys will behave a bit odd - the initial selection will be two lines in that case (so use C-SPC here).

Comment: I actually already knew that, and I've discovered that I can still stage just one line by confining the selection to a single line (i.e. using shift + left/right). This (especially + the discard action) is a killer feature :)